# How can I change the color of a placeholder in a text input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How can I change the color of a placeholder in a text input, but the first part of the text width yellow color, and the second part with the red. Html, CSS, JS.

Comment: I don't think you have this level of control over placholder style. You should use JavaScript elements instead, then you can style them how you like.

Comment: You can use a library like qTip to make fancy tooltips.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You will want to set the input to have to an empty placeholder. Than absolutely position a div on top of it with the text styled how you want. When that div is clicked/focus, hide it and focus on the input. if the input gets focus, hide the placeholder div and when it gets blur, show the placeholder div

Comment: You can select the element and add style to it. example: document.getElementById('myPlaceholder').style.color = 'red';

Comment: @TobyHarnish That wasn't the OP's question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use background-clip and a linear-gradient where browsers can handle it:

possible example:

```css
input::placeholder {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, yellow 3em, red 3em);
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  font-weight: bold;
  opacity: 1;/* because i want to see the yellow part ! */
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Some text">
```

Below, what it looks alike in Firefox :

[image]